# Display database table in PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to display my table from my MySQL database. It doesn't seem to work, I guess it's most likely something simple. If possible I would like to have the table look like just a normal table with no frills; just a border and to be able to fit in a normal sized page.  This is what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Profile Database </title>
</head>
<body>
<?
$connection = "connect.php";
require $connection;

mysql_select_db("bank");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM profiles";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<table border="2" style= "background-color: #84ed86; color: #761a9b; margin: 0 auto;" >
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>E-Mail</th>
<th>DOB</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>City</th>

<th>State</th>
<th>Zip Code</th>
<th>Offence</th>
<th>Notes</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

 <?php

 while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ))
 {
 echo <tr>
 <td>{$row\['id'\]}</td>
 <td>{$row\['fname'\]}</td>
 <td>{$row\['lname'\]}</td>
 <td>{$row\['email'\]}</td>
 <td>{$row\['dob'\]}</td>
 <td>{$row\['age'\]}</td>
 <td>{$row\['city'\]}</td> 
 <td>{$row\['state'\]}</td>
 <td>{$row\['zip'\]}</td>
 <td>{$row\['offence'\]}</td>
 <td>{$row\['notes'\]}</td>
 </tr>\n;
 }
 ?>
 </tbody>
 </table>

 <?php 
 mysql_close($connection); 
 ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You are not opening/closing your table rows - `<tr>...</tr>`

Comment: are you getting any errors?     it doesn't seem to work,means you are getting errors or o/p is not what you want..

Comment: you're missing the `<tr>` tags, also mysql_ functions are deprecated, you should not use them anymore, learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: thank you very much, i did not know about that.  lol  ive been reading about it for the past half hour now and it does seem like something i need to learn more about.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>E-Mail</th>
        <th>DOB</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Zip Code</th>
        <th>Offence</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
    </tr>
    <?php

        require "connect.php";

        mysql_select_db("bank");
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach($row as $column) {
                echo '<td>', $column, '</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: i tried that,  it does show the table names,  but nothing populates

Answer (score 0):

```
WHILE($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

should be either

```
WHILE($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

OR

```
WHILE($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

Also the mysql_* functions have been deprecated and relying on them is HIGHLY discouraged.

Kindly check the below discussions :-

[Deprecated MySql Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321620/deprecated-mysql-functions) 
[How to successfully rewrite old mysql-php code with deprecated mysql_* functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919277/how-to-successfully-rewrite-old-mysql-php-code-with-deprecated-mysql-functions) 
http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Use either `MySQLi` or `PDO`.

Comment: i managed to get the table to show the header, but the information from the table is still not populating.  we are connecting and it does recognize the db and table,

Comment: whats the diffrence between mysql and mysqli?

Answer (score 0):

```
<center><table border="1">
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>E-Mail</th>
<th>DOB</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>City</th>
<th>State</th>
<th>Zip Code</th>
<th>Offence</th>
<th>Notes</th>
</tr>
<?
$connection = "connect.php";
require $connection;

mysql_select_db("bank");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM profiles";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

WHILE($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

{
$id = $row ['id'];
$firstname = $row ['fname'];
$lastname = $row ['lname'];
$email = $row ['email'];
$dob = $row ['dob'];
$age = $row ['age'];
$city = $row ['city'];
$state = $row ['state'];
$zip = $row ['zip'];
$offence = $row ['offence'];
$nots = $row ['notes'];

echo '<tr>';   // change here
echo '<td>'.$id.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$firstname.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$lastname.'</td>'; 
echo '<td>'.$email.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$dob.'</td>'; 
echo '<td>'.$age.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$city.'</td>'; 
echo '<td>'.$state.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$zip.'</td>'; 
echo '<td>'.$offence.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$notes.'</td>'; 
echo '</tr>';  // change here
}

mysql_close();
?>


</table></center>
```

Comment: thank you very much.  this has helped me.  this shows the table head and a boarder but it doesnt seem to populate the data.  i am connecting and it does see the table.

Comment: welcome..please accept as answer click on the tick mark given to the left side of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php

$username = "your_name";
$password = "your_password";
$hostname = "localhost";

$dbconnect = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
$select=mysql_select_db("bank",$dbconnect) or die("Could not select bank");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM profiles";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<center><table border="1">
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>E-Mail</th>
    <th>DOB</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>Zip Code</th>
    <th>Offence</th>
    <th>Notes</th></tr>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

{
    $id = $row ['id'];
    $firstname = $row ['fname'];
    $lastname = $row ['lname'];
    $email = $row ['email'];
    $dob = $row ['dob'];
    $age = $row ['age'];
    $city = $row ['city'];
    $state = $row ['state'];
    $zip = $row ['zip'];
    $offence = $row ['offence'];
    $nots = $row ['notes'];

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$id.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$firstname.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$lastname.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$email.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$dob.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$age.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$city.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$state.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$zip.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$offence.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$notes.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table></center>

<?php
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrected Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Profile Database </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$connection = "connect.php";
require $connection;

mysql_select_db("bank");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM profiles";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<table border="2" style= "background-color: #84ed86; color: #761a9b; margin: 0 auto;" >
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>E-Mail</th>
<th>DOB</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>City</th>

<th>State</th>
<th>Zip Code</th>
<th>Offence</th>
<th>Notes</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

 <?php

 while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ))
 {
 ?>
 <tr>
 <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['fname'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['lname'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['dob'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['age'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['city'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['state'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['zip'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['offence'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['notes'];?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
 </tbody>
 </table>

 <?php 
 mysql_close($connection); 
 ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```